# Error:(59, 8) error: cannot access ActivityCompatApi23 class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23 not found

Tags: java, android, gradle

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    android {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user2.trafficmap"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}



dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
}
```

when I run my project I see this errors

> Error:(59, 8) error: cannot access ActivityCompatApi23 class file for
>   android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23 not found

and

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

How can I fix this problem ??? :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved this problem by add this code in build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> All `support` libraries need to be same version. If your compile SDK is 25,it's 25.3.0. If your compile SDK is 26, it's 26.0.0. Don't mix them

this should fix your problem

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the line

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'`

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```