# class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23 not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-activity, android-databinding

I want to try `databinding` for my new app but I've faced some issues. When I try to run my app I'm always getting this error `class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23 not found` I did some research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072953/error59-8-error-cannot-access-activitycompatapi23-class-file-for-android-su?rq=1) question that is related to my problem. But I can't found any answer that would solve my problem.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    flavorDimensions ""

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 24
        versionName "1.0"
        versionNameSuffix ""
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        baseline file("lint-baseline.xml")
        abortOnError false
    }

    task printLintResultsIfFailed {
        doLast {
            if (lintRelease.state.failure != null) {
                def report = new File(project.buildDir, "reports/lint-results-release.xml")
                print report.text
            }
        }
    }

    tasks.all {
        task -> if (task.name == "lintRelease") task.finalizedBy 'printLintResultsIfFailed'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar, dependsOn:[assemble]) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier "source"
}


dependencies {

    implementation project(path: ':integration')

    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.1'
}
```

Here's the full error
error:

```
cannot access ActivityCompatApi23
public abstract class NetworkActivity<T extends java.lang.Object> extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity implements courier.Hub, courier.Receiver<eu.myapp.registration.network.HttpResult<T>> {
                ^
  class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23 not found
```

As soon as  I deleted this line

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

I won't get that error

So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46929275/2724879 ?\

Comment: @YamenNassif yes but I don't use flexbox

Comment: its the idea, libraries miss match!

Answer (score 0):

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '25.3.0'
        }
    }
}
```

I got from this one : [Error:(59, 8) error: cannot access ActivityCompatApi23 class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072953/error59-8-error-cannot-access-activitycompatapi23-class-file-for-android-su?rq=1)